# values skipped or read twice when reading file

Tags: c++, file, structure

The point of this programme is to write to a file the first, middle, last name and test score of a student and if their score is between 40 and 50 points it has to output their names. However, it is skipping the names of some students or outputting them twice.
example:
input: n=2

Jon
Jones 
Jameson
41

George 
Peterson
Harrison
51

output: none

input: n=2
Jon
Jones 
Jameson
49

George 
Peterson
Harrison
43

output:
George 
Peterson
Harrison
George 
Peterson
Harrison

and that's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Student{
char first_name[20];
char second_name[20];
char last_name[20];
double score;
};
int main(){
Student students;
fstream file;
file.open("c:/students.txt",ios::in);
int n,i;
cout<<"n:";
cin>>n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++ ){
    cout<<"First name: ";
    cin>>students.first_name;
    cout<<"Second name: ";
    cin>>students.second_name;
    cout<<"Last name: ";
    cin>>students.last_name;
    cout<<"Score: ";
    cin>>students.sr_uspeh;
    file<<students.first_name<<" ";
    file<<students.second_name<<" ";
    file<<students.last_name<<" ";
    file<<students.score<<" ";

}
file.seekg(0);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    file>>students.first_name;
    file>>students.second_name;
    file>>students.last_name;
    file>>students.score;
    if(students.score>=40 && students.sr_uspeh<=50){
        cout<<students.first_name<<" ";
        cout<<students.second_name<<" ";
        cout<<students.last_name<<endl;
    }

}
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appropriate formatting would make reading the code easier. And [about using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: `Student students;` maybe you want to rename it to `Student student;` since you only hold 1 student at a time (the most recent one that was read).

Comment: `sr_uspeh` is not defined at all in `Student`. Got that deleted by accident or did you forget to rename some of the references to? So far, it won't compile, you should keep an eye on creating an [mre] (earlier name was minimal, *complete* and verifiable example, and *completeness* is certainly not met by your code...).

Comment: aconcagua, i changed the names up a bit because it was in bulgarian. it should be score

Comment: Well, good idea to write all code in English only even for yourself, you won't have that issue then... Apart from, don't you think that mixture of languages is somehow – errm... *unaesthetic*?

Comment: `file.open("c:/students.txt",ios::in);` – you open a file for reading, but then *write* to it? If you want to read *and* write, you should open it with `ios::in | ios::out`! Not fully sure, but I think operating on a file stream in a mode it wasn't opened for is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Still doesn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the names, `ios::in | ios::out` and some formats, then the code works as wanted

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Student{
    char first_name[20];
    char second_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    double score;
};
int main(){

    Student student;
    fstream file;
    file.open("fileName.txt",ios::in|ios::out);//You will input and output
    int n;
    cout<<"n:";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++ ){
        cout<<"\nFirst name: ";
        cin>>student.first_name;
        cout<<"\nSecond name: ";
        cin>>student.second_name;
        cout<<"\nLast name: ";
        cin>>student.last_name;
        cout<<"\nScore: ";
        cin>>student.score;

        cout<<"\nI got you inputs and I'm processing them.\n";

        file<<student.first_name<<" ";
        file<<student.second_name<<" ";
        file<<student.last_name<<" ";
        file<<student.score<<"\n";

    }

    file.seekg(0);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        file>>student.first_name;
        file>>student.second_name;
        file>>student.last_name;
        file>>student.score;

        if(student.score>=40 && student.score<=50){
            cout<<student.first_name<<" ";
            cout<<student.second_name<<" ";
            cout<<student.last_name<<endl;
        }

    }

    file.close();

return 0;
}
```

On inputing `n->4` then

```
name1 Jones Jameson 41
name2 Peterson Harrison 51
name3 Jones Jameson 49
name4 Peterson Harrison 43
```

The output is

```
I got you inputs and I'm processing them.
name1 Jones Jameson
name3 Jones Jameson
name4 Peterson Harriso
```